# Accessing the root directory in Windows bash

Tags: windows, bash, root

Where is the root folder pointing in the new Windows Bash console and how does one get to in from windows explorer.

Comment: Searching google led me to this question which answered my question. I see no reason for downvotes. The reason why windows is putting bash is specifically for developers -- the people this site is made for. Keep that in mind before downvoting

Answer (score 4):

It can be found here %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\lxss

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having trouble finding this folder, go to "Folder Options", click the View tab, and then you should select "Show hidden files and folders" in the list and remove the checkbox from "Hide protected operating system files" as well.